# Solve this system of equations using Gauss-Jordan elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

No matter what I do I can't seem to get this in the proper form.  Here is the system:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
3x+3y+12z&=6 \\
3x_1+x_2-2x_3&=2 \\
2x_1+2x_2+x_3&=10 \\
-x+2y+8z&=4
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Here is my base matrix:

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        3&3&12&6\\
        1&1&4&2 \\
        2&5&20&10 \\
        -1&2&8&4
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)R_1->R_1$

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        1&1&4&2 \\
        2&5&20&10 \\
        -1&2&8&4
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$(-2)R_1+R_3->R_3$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        1&1&4&2 \\
        0&3&12&6 \\
        -1&2&8&4
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_2<->R_4$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        -1&2&8&4 \\
        0&3&12&6 \\
        1&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_2<->R_3$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        0&3&12&6 \\
        -1&2&8&4 \\
        1&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_3+R_4->R_4$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        0&3&12&6 \\
        -1&2&8&4 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_2<->R_3$, $R_1+R_2->R_2$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        0&-1&-4&-2 \\
        0&3&12&7 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)R_3->R_3$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&1&4&2\\
        0&-1&-4&-2 \\
        0&1&4&2 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_1<->R_2$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        0&-1&-4&-2\\
        1&1&4&2 \\
        0&1&4&2 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_1+R_2->R_2$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        0&-1&-4&-2\\
        1&0&0&0 \\
        0&1&4&2 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_1<->R_2$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&0&0&0 \\
        0&-1&-4&-2 \\
        0&1&4&2 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_2<->R_3$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&0&0&0\\
        0&1&4&2 \\
        0&-1&-4&-2 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

$R_2+R_3->R_3$
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1&0&0&0\\
        0&1&4&2 \\
        0&0&0&0 \\
        0&1&4&2
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

I stopped here because I felt like I was going to be going into a circle and I felt like I've done way too many steps.  Please help!

Sorry for any mistakes, it took me awhile to type this up.

Comment: The final result is correct! Eliminate the last row (you have two rows of zero). Great job!

Comment: @Amzoti wow, thanks.